# Access vite app that's using a custom local domain from a mobile device

Tags: vue.js, networking, vite

I have worked on a Vue app that's currently running on localhost using vite. This app can be access on localhost through a custom domain I set up by modifying the hosts file on my machine.

Now I am trying to debug this app on a mobile device. I have tried to access the app using my IPV4 IP with the port of the vite server but that did not worked, the mobile can't access it.

Is there a way to access the computer custom domain from a mobile device that is connected on the same network? For instance, if the computer domain is "test.local" can I also use "test.local" on the mobile device to access the app?

Comment: You do this if you're able to change hosts on a mobile or use your own vpn or dns server. See https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/174515/how-to-edit-etc-hosts-file-in-non-rooted-phone and https://superuser.com/questions/1388096/use-custom-domains-in-local-network . Why wouldn't you access it by ip? This is how it's usually done.

Comment: The app uses an API that is also running locally and it's access through a custom local domain. If I access the app from mobile with the computer IP I get a blank page because the front-end can't make requests to back-end while on different domains. I need to access the app from mobile with the same custom domain I set on the computer.

Comment: You need either configure the app for cors in this scenario, or use vite dev proxy to avoid cors.